# Creating a table composite key from schema

Tags: mysql, relational-database

```
GCD needs a new database created to store all the necessary information about
their students, programmes, modules, and corresponding grade per module. The
detail is as follows:

– The college keeps track of each student’s name, student number, social security
number, address, phone, date-of-birth, and gender.

– Each programme is described by a programme code, name, description, duration
(number of years), level, and the cost.

– Each module has a module code, name, description, duration (number of weeks),
level (introductory, intermediate, advance).

– Grade stores student number, module code, and a letter grade (A, B, C, D, E, F).

Each programme enrolls students. Students then register modules. At the end of the
study duration of a module students receive their grades.
```

As this is a composite key how could I create a table from this?

`(sNumber, mCode, grade)`

I am trying it like this

```
Grade
CREATE TABLE grade (
sNumber INT NOT NULL,
mCode INT NOT NULL,
grade CHAR (1),
PRIMARY KEY(sNumber, mCode)
);
```

Would it be better practice to combine some commands like in case i change the mCode for a certain module?

`ON DELETE SET NULL & ON UPDATE CASCADE`

Comment: What you have seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As this is a composite key how could I create a table from this?
> (SQL for CREATE TABLE)

That will not work because the syntax is incorrect.  Straight RTFM issue.

- When you use `PRIMARY KEY` like that, it refers to a single column.
- For multiple columns, use the `CONSTRAINT` keyword, after the columns, before the closing bracket.  Use a meaningful constraint name (it will help when you are looking at lists during admin taks).
- The same applies for a composite `FOREIGN KEY`.

I will use the StudentGrade table from my answer to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58867612/484814).

```
CREATE TABLE student_grade (
    programme_code CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    module_code    CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    student_no     BIGINT  NOT NULL,
    grade          CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk
        PRIMARY KEY ( programme_code, module_code, student_no ),
    CONSTRAINT student_module_achieves_student_grade
        FOREIGN KEY               ( programme_code, module_code, student_no )
        REFERENCES student_module ( programme_code, module_code, student_no ),
    CONSTRAINT grade_ranks_student_grade
        FOREIGN KEY       ( grade )
        REFERENCES grade  ( grade )
    );
```

> Would it be better practice to combine some commands like in case i change the mCode for a certain module?
> `ON UPDATE CASCADE`

You have to understand what it does: when you UPDATE a PK column, the suite will cascade the changes to all child rows; grandchild rows; etc.

- It saves you writing a bunch of procedures that execute batch OLTP Transactions, to the cascade DELETE to all descendant tables.
- That would be banned in an OLTP system that uses a genuine SQL platform.
- For MySQL, which is not SQL, and has no chance of OLTP (no ACID Transactions; no Procedures; no Server Architecture), that is just fine, it is the alternative for small freeware systems.

> `ON DELETE SET NULL`

Understanding.  What that does is, for a child row that has an FK, when the parent row (in the parent table, where it is a PK) is DELETED, it sets the FK in the child row to NULL.

- Again, that is extremely bad practice, and banned in an OLTP system, but fine and common in freeware suites such as MySQL, because it does not have the SQL or Transaction or batch capabilities.
- Separate point.  When you have a Relational database, such as the data model I gave you, and it is a 'tight' database: it has Relational Integrity; etc, you really do not want to do that.  You want to be stopped (error message) when a parent that has descendants is deleted.
- After the system is bedded down, and the database is populated, imagine encountering a StudentGrade that has a NULL FK for ModuleCode.
  **No**.
- The JOINs will fail, and those rows will no longer appear in the relevant reports (in which they should, and are expected to appear).
  **No**.

And you definitely do not want this either:
`ON DELETE CASCADE`
because you will lose all the descendant rows.  **No**.

Comment: Shouldn't `grade_ranks_student_grade` reference `grade`?

Comment: @Spartako.  If you mean it should reference `student_grade` instead of `student_module`, yes.  Fixed.  Thanks.