# Creating a ERD from schema?

Tags: relational-database, erd

I was told to create a ERD diagram given the following

```
The college keeps track of each student’s name, student number, social security
number, address, phone, date-of-birth, and gender.

– Each programme is described by a programme code, name, description, duration
(number of years), level, and the cost.

– Each module has a module code, name, description, duration (number of weeks),
level (introductory, intermediate, advance).

– Grade stores student number, module code, and a letter grade (A, B, C, D, E, F).

Each program enrolls students. Students then register modules. At the end of the
study duration of a module students receive their grades.
```

I have made attributes for each entity

```
Student
(sNmber, SSN, sName, address, phone, DOB, gender)

Programme
(pCode, name, description, duration, level, cost)

Module
(mCode, name, description, duration, level)

Grade
(sNumber, mCode, grade)
```

My final diagram looks like this with entity relationships as well, I know I will have to break the M:N relationships down to two 1:M ex.
`Contains - programme_ Modules  (pCode, mCode)`

But my diagram seems off with the connecting Modules and Students to grade??

I am very new to this so would really appreciate some pointers

[image]

Comment: Please ask 1 clear specific non-duplicate question. "seems off" is unclear. Explain, referencing your textbook. Asking for "pointers" is not a valid SO question. Once you are done asking specific questions & you are not stuck & just want to ask "is this a reasonable basic straightforward design" then do that. See [ask],  [help], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) So also give (pseudo) DDL for the participations/FKs & cardinalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing is, that "schema" is not definitive enough to be called a schema.  Although the Keys may be obvious to you, they are not identified.  At best, it is a description, and an incomplete one.  Eg. if it were a schema, the M::N issue would be resolved, the table would be named, and all Keys would be identified.

In the ERD, you have not shown the attributes, which is required.  Next, you need to show which attributes are Keys.

### ERD

Here is an ERD, using somewhat improved symbols, erected from your description.

[image: LiamER]

Note the Relational Keys:

- They are composites
- They are required to:

  - **prevent duplicate rows**
  - enforce **Relational Integrity**, which is logical (as distinct from Referential Integrity, which is physical)
    Such as, we want to **constrain** a Student to register for a Module that is in the Programme that he is enrolled in.

### Relational Data Model

Obviously, the ERD is very limited, it does not have the capability to show all the definitions that are possible, and desired, in a Relational data model.  Further, as evidenced, it gets crowded very quickly.

It is quite ridiculous to teach ERD for Relational databases.  In the real world, we do not use ERD for modelling data, we use [IDEF1X](https://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/), the Standard for Relational data modelling since 1993.  This is what it looks like.

[image: LiamTA]

#### Note • Notation

- All my data models are rendered in [IDEF1X](https://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/)
- My [IDEF1X Introduction](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf) is essential reading for beginners

#### Note • Content

- The Primary Keys, as well as Alternate Keys, are explicit.
- The `Level` in `Module` is understood.  The `Level` in `Programme` is not clear.  It may or may not have some relation to the former.
- The **Predicates** can be *read* directly from the model.  If you need them in text form, please ask.